# How to start a SSH connection based on a configuration with Net::SSH?

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

`Net:SSH` offers me two class methods:

- [`configuration_for(host, use_ssh_config = true)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net%2FSSH.configuration_for)
- [`start(host, user, options = {}, &block)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/net-ssh/net-ssh/Net%2FSSH.start)

With `configuration_for()` I can get the configuration from the ssh config file as a hash and with `start()` I can initialize a new ssh connection.

Why is or is there no overload for `start()`, which takes a configuration hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/Config.html

The page says:

> Note that you will never need to use this class directly—you can control whether the OpenSSH configuration files are read by passing the :config option to Net::SSH.start. (They are, by default.)

Also take a look a the `translate` method:

> Given a hash of OpenSSH configuration options, converts them into a hash of Net::SSH options. Unrecognized options are ignored. The settings hash must have Strings for keys, all downcased, and the returned hash will have Symbols for keys.

So, from what I read, if there's interesting stuff in the configuration files, it will be picked up by default just by calling `start`.
Hope this helps you since I have no experience whatsoever with `Net::SSH`